# RegEx. How to remove blank space after a period before a punctuation character

Tags: r, regex

I have a question on regex. Suppose i have this string

```
"She gained about 55 pounds in...9 months. She was like an eating machine. ”Trump, a man who wants to be president: "
```

I want to remove every blank space after period and before character ” and delete character ”

For example this part of sentence

```
She was like an eating machine. ”Trump, a man who wants to be president:
```

should become

```
She was like an eating machine.Trump, a man who wants to be president: "
```

Thanks guys, regex is not easy to learn. Appreciate any help! bye
p.s i'm using software R but i think it's irrelevant since regex works in every programming language

*UPDATE*

I solved my problem and i'd like to share it, maybe could help someone else. I have this dataset downloaded from kaggle about trump and hillary tweet.

I have to do some cleaning before importing data on Knime(project at university).
I have  solved all encoding issues through gsub except this. i finally manage to solve it writing a csv file in R with Encoding UTF-8. Clearly i read that file in Knime with the same encoding

Comment: May be this could help:

var str = 'She was like an eating machine. "Trump, a man who wants to be president: '

str.replace(/\.\s"/g,".");

Comment: @Marco, did my answer work for you?

Comment: Yes sorry, it worked too. i mark your answer as the most heplful ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to match any number of whitespaces (1 or more) between a dot and the curly double quote, you may use

```
x <- "She gained about 55 pounds in...9 months. She was like an eating machine. ”Trump, a man who wants to be president: "
gsub("\\.\\s+”", ".", x)
## => [1] "She gained about 55 pounds in...9 months. She was like an eating machine.Trump, a man who wants to be president: "
```

The `\\.` matches a dot, `\\s+` matches 1 or more whitespace symbols and `”` matches a `”`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L9CR9F/1) and an [R demo](https://ideone.com/hPZtU6).

If there is only 1 regular space between the dot and the quote, you may use a fixed string replacement:

```
gsub(". ”", ".", x, fixed=TRUE)
```

See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/Q93TGF).

Answer (score 1):

May be this could help:

```
var str = 'She was like an eating machine. "Trump, a man who wants to be president. "New value'; 
str.replace(/\.\s"/g,".");
```

Answer (score 0):

http://regexr.com/ is a great tool for learning and testing regular expressions.

The only thing I'd add to Wiktor's answer is that it won't match `"machine.”Trump"`. To match any number of spaces after a dot and before a quote, use the `*` quantifier:

```
x <- "She gained about 55 pounds in...9 months. She was like an eating machine. ”Trump, a man who wants to be president: "
gsub("\\.\\s*”", ".", x)
```

Comment: Note that OP is using R, and regexr.com only supports JS regex flavor. E.g., `[.][^]*?"` will work nicely at regexr, but will not work in R. R basic R uses either TRE regex flavor (and I do not know a good online regex tester for this one) or PCRE (when used with `perl=TRUE`) - then http://regex101.com is a much better option.

Comment: Good point. https://regex101.com/ in pcre mode is probably a better choice for learning R-compatible regex. Your JS example can be made to work in R by modifying slightly and using perl mode:

Comment: The `[.][^]*?"` is equal to TRE `[.].*?"`, or `(?s)[.].*?"` in PCRE.

Comment: Or: `gsub("[.][^*]*?”", ".", x, perl = TRUE)`. Sorry for the delay, got distracted.

Comment: No, `[^]` matches any char, not any char but asterisk. Anyway, that is off-top already.

Comment: it's embarassing guys, I try the first answer( @WiktorStribiżew ) and it works , if I create the string and pass to gsub like a variable. If i try to apply gsub on the string extract from data it doesn't work

Comment: It means your input data is not what you posted. If possible get the original dara string and check for unprintable chars.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll do asap