# Removing white spaces after specific symbol ";"

Tags: r, trim, gsub

I have a question regarding removing white spaces within a character text inside a column data frame. This is my data frame column:

```
head(data$HO)
[1] "Lidar; Wind field; Temperature; Aerosol; Fabry-Perot etalon"                             
[2] "Compressive ghost imaging; Guided filter; Single-pixel imaging"
```

This question differs from this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261079/how-to-trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-in-r) as I want to remove only the spaces after the symbol ";" , so the output should look like this:

```
head(data$HO)
[1] "Lidar;Wind field;Temperature;Aerosol;Fabry-Perot etalon"                             
[2] "Compressive ghost imaging;Guided filter;Single-pixel imaging"
```

I have tried

```
data$HO <- gsub("\\;s", ";",data$HO)
```

but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trim leading and trailing whitespace in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261079/how-to-trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-in-r)

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264545/regex-how-to-remove-blank-space-after-a-period-before-a-punctuation-character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `;\s+` pattern and replace with `;`:

```
> x <- c("Lidar; Wind field; Temperature; Aerosol; Fabry-Perot etalon", "Compressive ghost imaging; Guided filter; Single-pixel imaging")
> gsub(";\\s+", ";", x)
[1] "Lidar;Wind field;Temperature;Aerosol;Fabry-Perot etalon"     
[2] "Compressive ghost imaging;Guided filter;Single-pixel imaging"
```

Pattern details:

- `;` - a semi-colon
- `\s+` - one or more whitespace chars.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nF7lQV/1).

Some more variations of the solution:

```
gsub("(*UCP);\\K\\s+", "", x, perl=TRUE)
gsub(";[[:space:]]+", ";", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more possible solution could be using `look-behind` `?<=` token. Just check for `;` behind `\s+` and replace space with nothing.

```
v <- c("Lidar; Wind field; Temperature; Aerosol; Fabry-Perot etalon", 
      "Compressive ghost imaging; Guided filter; Single-pixel imaging")

gsub("(?<=;)\\s+", "", v, perl = TRUE)

# Result:
# [1] "Lidar;Wind field;Temperature;Aerosol;Fabry-Perot etalon"     
# [2] "Compressive ghost imaging;Guided filter;Single-pixel imaging"
```